# Vue3 defineprops usage with v-model in child compoent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

As I understand you can not change the props value directly in the child component.
But I find out that this will work, I want to know the reason behind it.

For reference: I am using vue3+vite

For example:

```
<template>
    <input v-model="price"/>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>

defineProps({
    price : Number
});

</script>
```

this can change the props value based on the input. with no warning or error

but if I write this way

```
<template>
    <input v-model="props.price"/>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>

const props = defineProps({
    price : Number
});

</script>
```

there will be a warning in the console.

notice I didn't write any computed to handle the change of the props.

Is it a bad practice?

Comment: Your 1st example does not work either. You can easily test it using [Vue SFC playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/) (I'm unable to share the code as link is too long). It just throws the error `ReferenceError: price is not defined` because Vue does not expect (and allow) using prop as `v-model` argument directly (for obvious reasons)

Comment: But it does work on my local computer, I am using vite+vue3. I am wondering if it is because of the vite

Answer (score -1):

Both should issue warning. The reasoning is that the parent will not usualy be aware of the change unless it is mutated there.  It also allows the parent to validate the change. The idea is that only the owner of the data should modify it.

So emit an event instead.  The conventional way to write the code is.

```html
 <input :value="price" @input='$emit("input", $event)'/>
// or
 <input :value="price" @update:value='$emit("update:value", $event)'/>
// or
 <input :value="price" @input='$emit("update:value", $event)'/>
```

You can access both because Vue automatically exposes both the props object itself and all the props' properties into the template.

Comment: But the first one doesn't issue any warning. And I am not sure why I can access the price directly from the defineProps

Comment: yes, it should issue a warning.  that is my point.

Comment: They both do the same thing, and go againt Vue's best practices.   So the answer is avoid both, and the non-error version will most likely issue a warning in the future.